# How to prevent code duplication in lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have some Nodejs functions which contain duplicated code blocks.
I know that we can use lambda layer for shared libraries but i wanted to know that, is it possible to share codes too?
for example one of duplicated code is shown below

```
const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
});
```

i want to import this block into multiple functions without writing it over and over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to using layers (which is probably an overkill for sharing code only), you also have two other routers you can take:

- you can put the shared code in a separate file (so you end up with say 3 files in  your project - `lambda1.js`, `lambda2,js` and `shared.js`). You will then need to package your `lambda1` as a zip file containing `lambda1.js` and `shared.js` for example.
- you could keep all the code in a single file (say `alllambda.js`) and have different handler functions configured (`exports.handler1`, `exports.handler2`) - when you configure your AWS Lambda functions, `Lambda1` has `Handler` configured as `handler1` and `Lambda2` has `handler2`. This obviously does not scale well (and has the extra downside of sharing the initialization code).

Comment: what if when i use lambda layer with library and codes together ?

Comment: Shared.js will be copied with all the lambda functions still in the case 1. So code duplication is still there.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a separate Lambda with all of the shared code. Then you can invoke the shared Lambda from within all the other lambdas, or use a "Main" lambda to handle the back/forth.